# I can't understand the sentence from this video

Tags: listening

This is the video : [Video](https://youtu.be/LVmOric9nUo?t=226) (from 3:47 to 3:58)
The question for the homework is:

> What was the only flaw of the design of The Globe?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this? We're not a homework completion service unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I agree  the speech is a little muffled at that part of the video and would be difficult for a non-native speaker to understand.

My transcription of the vocals is:

> The only flaw with the globe was that the acoustics were awful due to its open air top. The actors would have to yell rather loud to project ...

Hope that helps you.

Comment: The only flaw with the globe was **that** the acoustics were awful due to its open air top.

Comment: @GoDucks - Yes, I agree after re-listening.